# Constant errors in the method for smallest coprime number

Tags: haskell

So I'm new to Haskell, and I've been trying to implement the function which finds the smallest coprime number. I have another function for calculating GCD.

I've already tried various ways to implement my function, however, they all failed.

```
smallestCoPrimeOf :: Int -> Int
smallestCoPrimeOf a 
| gcd a b == 1  =  b
| otherwise     = gcd a (b+1)
```

OR replacing the last two lines with

```
b = 2

if (gcd a b) == 1 

then b 

else gcd a (b+1)
```

OR

```
let b = 2

if (gcd a b) == 1  then b else gcd a (b+1)
```

And all of these end up throwing errors like "parse error on input ‘|’", or "parse error on input ‘if’". Every time I google something and try correcting the mistake, the same error repeats/ anothe one appears. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Are you running this in GHCi or are you writing this in a file? Remember that Haskell source code and GHCi work differently.

Comment: I’m not sure how your `if`s are formatted because it looks like the formatting got lost in the question (you can [edit] it back in), but those `|` lines need to be indented to be “inside” `smallestCoPrimeOf`. So put one or more spaces before each. That’ll lead you to the more relevant, non-parse errors :)

Comment: I've tried it with parsing, and it still throws the same errors. Yes, I'm writing this in a file.

Comment: How can I paste pics somewhere so it would be clearer?

Comment: Don't paste pics. SO policy is against it. Copy and paste the error _text_, should the need arise: most text interfaces will allow you to do that. More on the problem here: to solve this task it's easier if you define a (recursive) function `smallestCoPrimeOfFrom a b` which find the first coprime `>=b`. Once you do that, you can have `smallestCoPrimeOf a = smallestCoPrimeOfFrom a 2` and complete your task.

Answer (score 2):

In Haskell, indentation matters. You must indent the lines to show what lines are subordinate to others. This is what allows Haskell to avoid using so many brackets, like other languages. Like so:

```
smallestCoPrimeOf :: Int -> Int
smallestCoPrimeOf a 
    | gcd a b == 1  =  b
    | otherwise     = gcd a (b+1)
```

The amount of indentation is not perscribed, as long as it is consistent.

You could also write:

```
smallestCoPrimeOf :: Int -> Int
smallestCoPrimeOf a =
    let b = 2
    in if (gcd a b) == 1
       then b
       else gcd a (b+1)
```

Notice how `let` and `in` align, as well as `if`-`then`-`else`.

If you're using GHCi, remember to put multi-line declarations in `:{`-`:}`:

```
λ> :{
λ| smallestCoPrimeOf a 
λ|   | gcd a b == 1  =  b
λ|   | otherwise     = gcd a (b+1)
λ| :}
```

There are other issues with your code, but these are for you to discover.

Comment: So I used 
| gcd a b == 1  =  b
where b = 2
| otherwise     = gcd a (b+1), with proper lining, and it still says "parse error on input ‘|’". Is it an indentation-related issue as well?

Comment: And as for    
let b = 2
    in if (gcd a b) == 1
       then b
       else gcd a (b+1)    it says "parse error on input ‘let’", and google doesn't help either.

Comment: @LifeIsShit I edited the second example he gave with the correct syntax (it was missing an `=` in line 2)